# Equal distance for 2 pairs of objects

Tags: adobe-illustrator, spacing

The following are 4 text boxes. I would like to relocate `lmn` such that the vertical distance between `lmn` and `hij` is the same as the vertical distance between `efg` and `abc`.

Does anyone know how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Try using Smart Guides: [see example](https://imgur.com/uneafvy)

Answer (score 0):

In the Align Panel, make sure Align to Selection is ON, then

1. Select abc and hij, align to top.
2. Select efg and lmn, align to top.

[image]

Comment: But I don't want the 3 items other than `lmn` to be changed.

Comment: Well, yeah, there are different ways to achieve this. This solution is still valid, if you need to preserve that vertical position, you can move the Y value of the hij+lmn group to the previous Y value of the hij item. There are a couple of other ways to do it. Scott's answer is very good too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately nobody knows what you actually are going to draw. That very likely makes given answers sub-optimal, but anyway you'll get some. Assuming nothing else than lmn can be moved you can draw a box between the baselines of abc and efg. It snaps if you have Smart guides and Snap to points checked. It's done in the middle in the next image:

[image]

Then move the box below hij and finally move lmn.

Comment: it's indeed one way to realize this. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain one needs **4** text frames. Seems like, at most, 2 would be sufficient

Although the sample *could* be done with just 1 text area - 3 line feeds and 2 tabs....

[image]

**[Leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading)** ensures equidistance between lines.

I **do** realize the image in the question is most likely *not* the *actual* content. So, some adjustments would be required in all likelihood. And tabs *may* not be feasible or desired if the distance between the two sets of text is quite great.

However, in that case, 2 text areas may be better. Again, *[leading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leading)* - if set the same in both text areas - would ensure the distance between the top line and second line of text is the same in both text areas.

In broad, general terms, using the least amount of text frames necessary often makes things easier in construction specifically *because* one can take advantage of things like leading or paragraph options. Less text frames also makes editing in the future much, much easier. Most designers aren't measuring baseline distances, they are adjusting leading.

Comment: Just realized.. I was thinking *InDesign* when I posted this. Although, it would all still be true and work in Illustrator with Area Text.